# Read an file of int with blank lines and save to a array - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, file

Im trying to read a txt file and save into a array but im only getting null in the output of my array. What am i missing?

A part of the txt file, and yes it is with these blank lines between the numbers

```
306741
581016
783580

529978
772824
54939
797499
235178

675900
365768
561760

986962
242452

621124
555822
80045

914383
634731
18956
```

The code that creates the array

```
public class Stack {
protected final int MAX=1000000;
protected Integer[]pilha;

Stack(){
    pilha = new Integer[MAX];
}

void add(Integer newElement){
    int i;
    for(i=0;pilha[i]!=null;i++);
    pilha[i]= newElement;
}
```

And the main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("D:\\entradas\\tarefas1000.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    Stack guardar=new Stack();
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        guardar.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(guardar.pilha));

}
  }
```

Comment: `for(i=0;pilha[i]!=null;i++);` has a semicolon at the end so repeats `;` - empty statement.

Comment: @JoopEggen it's supposed to do that. The purpose is to find the next available array index.

Comment: Debug your application. Make sure the file is being read and that `Stack::add` is actually called.

Comment: I reproduced this to run in my local system. And it works fine. Can you show the actual output you are getting?

Comment: @Abra I'm sorry, I'll do it now!

Comment: If the  input file contains only empty lines, the stack is not filled because no `int` value could be read by the scanner.  If there's a non-int value, an `InputMismatchException` is thrown.  If file contains only empty/blank lines and valid ints - it can be read succesfully.

Comment: @ankitbeniwal I'm basically getting 10000 "null" text

Comment: @Niddog for your data sample, the output for `MAX=30` is as follows: `[306741, 581016, 783580, 529978, 772824, 54939, 797499, 235178, 675900, 365768, 561760, 986962, 242452, 621124, 555822, 80045, 914383, 634731, 18956, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]`

Comment: What a dumb mistake I'm sorry for bothering you, however, is there any way I can print without nulls and without using an `IF`?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Stack {

    protected final int MAX = 1_000_000;
    protected int[] pilha;
    private int numero;
    
    Stack(){
        pilha = new int[MAX];
    }
    
    void add(int newElement){
        pilha[numero] = newElement;
        ++numero;
    }

    public int size() {
        return numero;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        boolean needsComma = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numero; ++i) {
            if (needsComma) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(pilha[i]);
            needsComma = true;
        };
        sb.append(']');
        return sb.toString(); // Arrays.toString(pilha);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Stack guardar = new Stack();
    Path file = Paths.get("D:\\entradas\\tarefas1000.txt");
    Files.lines(file) //This method needs a parameter to work on
    .forEach(line -> {
        if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
            guardar.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
        }
    });
    System.out.println(guardar);
}
```

Comment: Actually the advantage of `Paths.get()` is that you don't need to hard-code the separators. You can write: `Paths.get("D:", "entradas", "tarefas1000.txt")`

Comment: @Abra thanks. `Path` is a newer class than `File` (disk drive files) which is a generalisation (also class path resource files, files inside a zip etc.). The class `Files` offers many goodies one can do with a `Path`, like reading a file into a string, and as above reading all lines.